# Available encoder to IIS smooth streaming

Tags: smooth-streaming, expression-encoder

I am trying to make a web site with IIS smooth streaming but all the tutorials and examples that I found use Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 pro. According to them only the pro version is capable of using H.264 compression. But the problem is Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 pro is discontinued and the available free version dose not support H.264 compression. So I want to know whether there any other encoders(commercial or freeware) that I can use with IIS 7. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Sorenson Squeeze](http://www.sorensonmedia.com/squeeze/squeeze-9/) with relative success for on-demand video encoding. It does not do live video but can successfully encode plan video files into many different formats. This is the "cheap" encoder I recommend for everyday light use. It does most of what Expression Encoder used to do.

For professional-quality encoding needs, you will want to look towards products from [Harmonic](http://www.harmonicinc.com/), [Envivio](http://www.envivio.com/) and similar vendors. Together with high quality and broad feature set you will, of course, also be faced with a significant pricetag.

There are also [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/) and [Unified Streaming Platform](http://www.unified-streaming.com/) which offer such services for relatively low cost, though my personal opinion of them is not very high - they seem more marketing than functionality oriented businesses.